# Read back data stored in a texture

Tags: opengl, textures

I have got a texture which is updated from a fragment shader that calculates points positions.

What is the good way to read it back so it could be drawn as primitives ?

Comment: Use transform feedback to write points to a vertex buffer instead of a fragment shader.

Comment: The easy way to read data from a texture is with [glGetTexImage](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glGetTexImage.xml). The fast way is using [FBOs](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to draw using the data from the texture, reading back to host memory is a waste and slow (But for reference you could use `glGetTexImage` or `glReadPixels`).

- Instead, you can draw primitives without providing vertex positions and read them from your texture in the vertex shader (bound as a sampler and using `texelFetch` for example).

  The coordinates for texel fetch can come from a per-vertex attribute (just like regular texture coordinates), or you can use `gl_VertexID` to calculate them implicitly.
- As @ColonelThirtyTwo said, you can also use transform feedback. Not using your texture and doing the computation in the fragment shader, but replacing it with computation in a vertex shader. Here the varying variables normally interpolated to the fragment shader get packed and saved in a buffer, still on the GPU.

Comment: since you're in a vertex shader what about the texture coordinate ? thanx

Comment: @user46759 as said, you can pass them in via an attribute or compute them implicitly based on the vertex id. for example, instead of a per-vertex position you have a per-vertex where-in-the-texture-the-position-is. or each vertex gets its own texel with something like `ivec2(gl_VertexID % width, gl_VertexID / width)`. `texelFetch()` and `texture()`/`texture2D()` also work in vertex shaders, except on really ancient cards.